# Logout/login redirect CSS issue

Tags: functions, css, redirect, wp-login-form, logout

I'm using WordPress Multisite. When I use `wp_logout_url()`, I get redirected to the login page but somehow I end at a different login page without any styles applied

```
   <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

That's the only logout function I'm calling.

And my login functions look like this:

```
  // 1. Custom login CSS
function my_login_stylesheet() { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="custom_wp_admin_css"  href="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/style.css'; ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_stylesheet' );

// 2. Change logo URL
add_filter('login_headerurl', 'my_custom_url');
function my_custom_url(){
return "http://mydomain.com/domain";
}

// 3. Add personal message to login

function custom_login_message() {
$message = '<p class="message">KOMM - App</p>';
return $message;
}
add_filter('login_message', 'custom_login_message');

// 4. Change login button text

add_action( 'login_form', 'wpse17709_login_form' );
function wpse17709_login_form()
{
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse17709_gettext', 10, 2 );
}
function wpse17709_gettext( $translation, $text )
{
    if ( 'Log In' == $text ) {
        return 'OK';
    }
    return $translation;
}

// 5. Redirect user to index-page after login
add_filter('login_redirect', 'plugin_admin_redirect'); 
function plugin_admin_redirect($redirect_to, $url_redirect_to = '', $user = null) { 
    return get_option('siteurl');

}
```

I guessing that I need to apply function 1 and 2 to the `wp_logout_url()` function to get the CSS applied. I've been trying for long now.

Login page:

[image: Login page with css applied before login]

And when I logout I get to next screenshot:

[image]

Logout/login page that I'm being redirected to:

[image: Login/logout without stylesheet applied]

I would appreciate if someone could explain or get me on the right path.

**NOTE:**

*Login link:*

```
/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdesignmobile.se%2Fgomobile%2Fkrisdemo%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

*Logout link:*.

```
/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdesignmobile.se%2Fgomobile%2Fkrisdemo%2F&_wpnonce=17d70b468f
```

Comment: Are you sure a "redirect is involved at all? Looks like the same page with different, or missing, CSS.

Comment: Yes its involved , see updated question. That happens when i click logout. Im not sure if im geeting redirected to another page or to the same page but no css applied.

Comment: Yes, you do get redirected at logout but ordinarily the redirect sends you from `wp-login.php` to `wp-login.php`. What changes are the `$_GET` parameters. Are you at `wp-login.php` in both cases?

Comment: No its not the same link really.
1. When someone is trying to reach the website , ull be redirected to wp-login (pic1) & (link1)
2.When you sign in and log out (pic2) & (link2). **Question Updated again** @s_ha_dum

Comment: If same page but missing CSS , what is causing it ? @s_ha_dum

Comment: Is it the same page or not? You just said, "its not the same link".

Comment: It looks like the same page as your said. Only the GET_ changes. Everything is the same until /wp-admin.php?

Comment: Your code loads the stylesheet for both pages. I checked. The problem must be with the **rules** in the stylesheet.

Comment: I checked and every  class and ids are the same. So my only guess its that im being redirected to wordpress default login instead of my custom login page?

Comment: ***Custom login page***??? If I am not mistaken this is the first mention of a custom login page in contrast to `login.php`. You are making this very confusing.

Comment: Sorry its only custom css*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to the page you're currently on use:

```
wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

or

```
wp_logout_url( get_permalink() );
```

Or if you want to redirect to another site use the [allowed_redirect_hosts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url#Logout_and_Redirect_to_Another_Site) function.

Comment: I just want when i logout ill get redirected to (pic1) again...

Comment: Then try the above `wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );` or `wp_logout_url( get_permalink() );`

Comment: REQUEST_URI didnt work , same issue and get_permalink() dont allow me to logout.

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation above re: "allowed_redirect_hosts"?

Comment: Yes ive tried it and its the same issue. Sems im being redirected to wordpress default login instead of my custom login. Its only a guess.